# Does assign an object to a Map from another immutable Map mean deep cloning?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

When I have two Immutable Map objects:

```
const MapA = Immutable.fromJS({person: {name: 'Peter', age: 18}, parent: 'Sally'});
let MapB = Immutable.fromJS({prop1: 'testing'});

MapB = MapB.set('person', MapA.get('person'));
```

Is the object {name: 'Peter', age: 18} shared among two maps or is there a way to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImmutableJS shares instances. In your case, the snapshot instance `person` is shared for both MapA and MapB. You can verify this by adding custom plain JS properties on this instance and verify it for both MapA version and MapB version. You will find they have the same values.

Here's a fiddle for you... https://jsfiddle.net/HaZardous/0Ls5gdht/.

Here's the fiddle code for reference -

```
var MapA = Immutable.fromJS({person: {name: 'Peter', age: 18}, parent: 'Sally'}),
MapB = Immutable.fromJS({prop1: 'testing'}),
person = MapA.get('person');

MapB = MapB.set('person', person);

person["nationality"] = "US";

console.log("Direct ref: " + person["nationality"]);
console.log("MapA ref: " + MapA.get('person')["nationality"]);
console.log("MapB ref: " + MapB.get('person')["nationality"]);
```

Output

```
Direct ref: US
MapA ref: US
MapB ref: US
```